# How does Truffle Deployer translate arguments from JavaScript to Solidity?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract

I have a Truffle migration that looks something like this;

```
var MyContract = artifacts.require("./MyContract.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(MyContract,[
    {
      "title": "President",
      "choices": [
        {"name": "Mary", "votes": 10},
        {"name": "Maria", "votes": 10},
        {"name": "Maryam", "votes": 10}
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Vice President",
      "choices": [
        {"name": "John", "votes": 10},
        {"name": "Juan", "votes": 10},
        {"name": "Abdullah", "votes": 10}
      ]
    }
  ], {gas: 2900000});
};
```

And `MyContract.sol` looks like this;

```
contract MyContract {
  // Define some public variables here...  
  function MyContract(bytes32[] myArray) { // Not sure this line is right
    // How do I access constructor arguments here?
  }
}
```

The problem is, I don't know what Truffle translates my constructor arguments to in Solidity. I know I need to tell the constructor what type of data to expect, but I don't know what that data will look like, or what syntax to use to access it. [The deployer docs are on the Truffle website](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations#deployer-api), but they only explain that you can pass the arguments, not how to access them in Solidity.

Edit: It looks like the JSON interface that truffle-contract uses might be a piece of the puzzle. `interface.abi` is an array that contains this element for the constructor;

```
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "myArray",
      "type": "bytes32[]"
    }
  ],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "constructor"
}
```

Comment: I would also expect the Contract Instance API docs to cover this, but they don't: https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-contract#contract-instance-api

Comment: From the information in the Solidity docs about data types, and a few of my own experiments, it seems like I may have to rely on primitive byte array data types to pass in arguments to the constructor. http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html

Answer (score 0):

I meet same problem, fortunately I got answer in the following link:
['Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5)\n'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109544/error-invalid-arrayify-value-argument-value-value-code-invalid-argumen)

I see you want to pass an btyes[] type parameter, in javascript, it should be a array of hex string, for example:

```
var myArray = ["0x00", "0x00", ..., "0x00"]
```

The content of array is what you want to pass to function in hex string type

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).