# 'Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5)\n'

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have the following solidity function that I'm calling from truffle:

```
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 id,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes memory data
    ) public virtual override {
        require(
            from == _msgSender() || isApprovedForAll(from, _msgSender()),
            "ERC1155: caller is not owner nor approved"
        );
        _safeTransferFrom(from, to, id, amount, data);
    }


    function _safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 id,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes memory data
    ) internal virtual {
        require(to != address(0), "ERC1155: transfer to the zero address");

        address operator = _msgSender();

        _beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, _asSingletonArray(id), _asSingletonArray(amount), data);

        uint256 fromBalance = _balances[id][from];
        require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC1155: insufficient balance for transfer");
        unchecked {
            _balances[id][from] = fromBalance - amount;
        }
        _balances[id][to] += amount;
        
        if (!isOwner(to)) {
            owners.push(to);
        }

        emit TransferSingle(operator, from, to, id, amount);

        _doSafeTransferAcceptanceCheck(operator, from, to, id, amount, data);
    }
```

This is my call from truffle:

```
t = await i.safeTransferFrom(accounts[1], accounts[9], 0, "6666666666666666666", "", {from: accounts[1]})
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught:
Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:11
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:2:49
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:273:12)
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:140:14)
    at runScript (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:328:1)
    at Console.interpret (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:343:1)
    at bound (domain.js:413:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:424:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:817:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:337:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:666:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:1010:14) {
  reason: 'invalid arrayify value',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'value',
  value: '',
  hijackedStack: 'Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5)\n' +
    '    at lib_esm_Logger.makeError (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:166:1)\n' +
    '    at lib_esm_Logger.throwError (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:175:1)\n' +
    '    at lib_esm_Logger.throwArgumentError (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:178:1)\n' +
    '    at lib_esm_arrayify (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/bytes/lib.esm/index.js:87:1)\n' +
    '    at BytesCoder.encode (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/bytes.js:9:17)\n' +
    '    at /usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/array.js:49:1\n' +
    '    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at pack (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/array.js:43:1)\n' +
    '    at TupleCoder.encode (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/tuple.js:19:16)\n' +
    '    at AbiCoder.encode (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/abi-coder.js:82:1)\n' +
    '    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:121:1)\n' +
    '    at /usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:439:1\n' +
    '    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at Object._encodeMethodABI (/usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:438:6)\n' +
    '    at /usr/local/Cellar/truffle/5.4.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/execute.js:182:1\n' +
    '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)'
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Hmm try “0x” instead of “”.

Comment: maybe also use BigInteger instead of numbers in “…”

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit strange that answers about ETH are so few.

I met the same problem. for your case, running :

```
t = await i.safeTransferFrom(accounts[1], accounts[9], 0, "6666666666666666666", "", {from: accounts[1]})
```

will get this error:

```
Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:11
```

notice the error backtrace `value=""`, means here you got the problem

convert `""` to `0x` or `0x00` will work, because in your function, you declared a parameter with type `bytes`, which "seems" only accept parameter starting with `0x`.